# Create procedure that deletes data from several tables. SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-delete

I need to create a procedure that allows me to delete data from several tables at once, searching through the `CUIT`. There are four tables shown here:

[image]

I must pass a `CUIT` value in, and if it matches any item saved in the database, I need it to be deleted. I could not find the syntax to be able to erase more than two tables at once, if you could give me a hand I would greatly appreciate it. I clarify by the doubts that the procedure is actually much larger, in total it would be about 12 tables, but as I am interested only the syntax I pass this fragment.

I have problems trying to join the tables using `INNER JOIN`.

I am using SQL Server 2016. Thank you

Comment: *"I could not find the syntax to be able to erase more than two tables at once"* because there is no such syntax. A DML statement can only effect one table at a time. Considering you want to `DELETE` from 4 tables, that means you will need 4 `DELETE` statements.

Comment: And how could I do this task then? What is used to perform these types of actions? Because I need to erase all the information related to that CUIT, and if or if I have to make any relationship between the tables. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your design, i would implement Cascading on your Foreign Key. This is a sample, but should get you on the right path:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ParentTable (PK int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                              I int);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ChildTable1 (PK int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                              FK int,
                              S varchar(10));

CREATE TABLE dbo.ChildTable2 (PK int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                              FK int,
                              S varchar(10));

CREATE TABLE dbo.ChildTable3 (PK int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                              FK int,
                              S varchar(10));
GO
--Create keys with CASCADE ON DELETE
ALTER TABLE dbo.ChildTable1 ADD CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY (FK) REFERENCES dbo.ParentTable(PK) ON DELETE CASCADE;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.ChildTable2 ADD CONSTRAINT FK2 FOREIGN KEY (FK) REFERENCES dbo.ParentTable(PK) ON DELETE CASCADE;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.ChildTable3 ADD CONSTRAINT FK3 FOREIGN KEY (FK) REFERENCES dbo.ParentTable(PK) ON DELETE CASCADE;
GO


INSERT INTO dbo.ParentTable (I)
VALUES(1),(7),(9);

INSERT INTO dbo.ChildTable1 (FK,
                            S)
VALUES(1,'abc'),(3,'def');

INSERT INTO dbo.ChildTable2 (FK,
                            S)
VALUES(1,'xyz'),(2,'qwe');

INSERT INTO dbo.ChildTable3 (FK,
                            S)
VALUES(1,'123');
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.ParentTable PT
     LEFT JOIN dbo.ChildTable1 CT1 ON PT.PK = CT1.PK
     LEFT JOIN dbo.ChildTable2 CT2 ON PT.PK = CT2.PK
     LEFT JOIN dbo.ChildTable3 CT3 ON PT.PK = CT3.PK;

--1, as we're going to DELETE that
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ChildTable1 CT1
WHERE CT1.FK = 1;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.ChildTable1 CT2
WHERE CT2.FK = 1;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.ChildTable1 CT3
WHERE CT3.FK = 1;
GO

--Perform the DELETE, which will CASCADE to the child tables.    
DELETE FROM dbo.ParentTable
WHERE PK = 1;
GO
--no rows
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ParentTable PT
     LEFT JOIN dbo.ChildTable1 CT1 ON PT.PK = CT1.PK
     LEFT JOIN dbo.ChildTable2 CT2 ON PT.PK = CT2.PK
     LEFT JOIN dbo.ChildTable3 CT3 ON PT.PK = CT3.PK;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.ChildTable1 CT1
WHERE CT1.FK = 1;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.ChildTable1 CT2
WHERE CT2.FK = 1;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.ChildTable1 CT3
WHERE CT3.FK = 1;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.ChildTable3;
DROP TABLE dbo.ChildTable2;
DROP TABLE dbo.ChildTable1;
DROP TABLE dbo.ParentTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you do not want to alter your database schema, you could go for `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER`.

Trigger allows you to perform any tasks when a particular action is performed. In this case, you can write `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger on your parent/master table and inside trigger you can delete related entries from child tables. Have a look at below example.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Gestiones
(
    id_gestione int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CUIT INT
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ChildGestione1
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    id_gestioneFK int REFERENCES Gestiones(id_gestione),
    Description VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ChildGestione2
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    id_gestioneFK int REFERENCES Gestiones(id_gestione),
    Description VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ChildGestione3
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    id_gestioneFK int REFERENCES Gestiones(id_gestione),
    Description VARCHAR(100)
);


INSERT INTO dbo.Gestiones (CUIT)
VALUES (10), (20), (30), (40);

INSERT INTO dbo.ChildGestione1 (id_gestioneFK, Description)
VALUES (1,'abc'), (2,'efg');

INSERT INTO dbo.ChildGestione2 (id_gestioneFK, Description)
VALUES (1,'abc'), (3,'pqr');

INSERT INTO dbo.ChildGestione3 (id_gestioneFK, Description)
VALUES (1,'abc'), (3,'pqr'), (4,'stu');

GO


SELECT * FROM dbo.Gestiones
SELECT * FROM dbo.ChildGestione1
SELECT * FROM dbo.ChildGestione2
SELECT * FROM dbo.ChildGestione3

DELETE FROM Gestiones where CUIT = 10

SELECT * FROM dbo.Gestiones
SELECT * FROM dbo.ChildGestione1
SELECT * FROM dbo.ChildGestione2
SELECT * FROM dbo.ChildGestione3


CREATE TRIGGER InsteadOfDELETETriggerExample ON [Gestiones]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id_gestione INT

    SELECT @id_gestione = id_gestione FROM deleted

    IF @id_gestione IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM ChildGestione1 WHERE id_gestioneFK = @id_gestione
        DELETE FROM ChildGestione2 WHERE id_gestioneFK = @id_gestione
        DELETE FROM ChildGestione3 WHERE id_gestioneFK = @id_gestione
        /*...
        and so on...you can right as many child tables as you have
        */

        -- At the last, delete the entry from parent table
        DELETE FROM Gestiones WHERE id_gestione = @id_gestione
    END

    PRINT 'Successfully deleted references of CUIT column from all the child tables.'
END
GO


DROP TRIGGER InsteadOfDELETETriggerExample
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.ChildGestione3;
DROP TABLE dbo.ChildGestione2;
DROP TABLE dbo.ChildGestione1;
DROP TABLE dbo.Gestiones;
```

Above code will work only for one delete entry on master table, if the delete operation is affecting more than one entry in parent table then you need to `JOIN` the `deleted` table with your child tables for deleting.