# Deleting null records from 3 tables using join

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables : artist, title and track.

I want to delete the **whole record** from any of 3 tables if there any null value in any row.

My code :

```
DELETE cdArtist
FROM cdArtist AS a
    LEFT JOIN cdTitle AS t ON a.cdArtistID=t.cdArtistID
    LEFT JOIN cdTrack AS tr ON t.cdTitleID=tr.cdTitleID
WHERE 
a.cdArtistID IN (NULL, 0) AND
    a.Name IN (NULL, 0) AND
    a.Name IN (NULL, 0) AND
    t.cdArtistID IN (NULL, 0) AND
    t.cdTitleID IN (NULL, 0) AND
    t.DateTime IN (NULL, 0) AND
    tr.cdTitleID IN (NULL, 0) AND
    tr.cdTrackID IN (NULL, 0) AND
    tr.SongTitle IN (NULL, 0) AND
    tr.TrackNo IN (NULL, 0) AND
    tr.TrackNo IN (NULL, 0)
SELECT *
FROM cdArtist AS a
    LEFT JOIN cdTitle AS t ON a.cdArtistID=t.cdArtistID
    LEFT JOIN cdTrack AS tr ON t.cdTitleID=tr.cdTitleID
```

Comment: Short of cascading deletion, or maybe a trigger, you will need to issue three separate delete statements.

Comment: NULL can never be equated to anything (even NULL) - which is what you attempt with something like `tr.TrackNo in (Null, 0)`. Post a script that reduces and simplifies your goal and others are more likely to help. But the short answer is - a delete statement by itself can only alter the contents of a single table.

Comment: A single `DELETE` statement can only delete from single table at a time. Have a look at similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60318835/create-procedure-that-deletes-data-from-several-tables-sql-server/60332522#60332522

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
select cdArtistID into #artistsToDelete from cdArtist where Name is null

insert into #artistsToDelete select cdArtistID from cdTitle where cdTitleID is null or [DateTime] is null

select cdTitleID into #titlesToDelete from cdTitle where cdArtistID is null or [DateTime] is null

insert into #titlesToDelete select cdTitleID from cdTrack where SongTitle is null or TrackNo is null

select cdTrackID into #tracksToDelete from cdTrack where SongTitle is null or TrackNo is null

delete from cdArtist where cdArtistID is null or cdArtistID in (select distinct cdArtistID from #artistsToDelete)

delete from cdTitle where cdTitleID is null or cdTitleID in (select distinct cdTitleID from #titlesToDelete )

delete from cdTrack where cdTrackID is null or cdTrackID in (select distinct cdTrackID from #tracksToDelete )
```